# jqgrid loading on Button Click

Tags: jqgrid

Jqgrid load with data on pageload. When I try to load the grid on a button click grid load with the data but in the next moment the full grid get disappear if I use the grid on a content page with master page and the rows get disappear if I use a page without master page. Is there any solution for this? Thanks
Added a demo

Note: grid is disappearing on every postback
When I removed the update panel from master page , grid is not disappearing but the data on the grid is disappering

```
    jQuery("#jqgItemDetails").jqGrid({
        url: '',
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ['UPC Code', 'OLD UPC', 'Item Description', 'Old Item Desc', 'Size UOM', 'Old Size UOM', 'Department', 'Category',
            'Tax Description', 'WIC/CVV', 'Label', 'Last Movement', 'Last Purchase', 'Item Added', 'Comment', 'Store Number'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'UPC_Code', index: 'UPC_Code', width: 90, stype: 'text' },
                    { name: 'UPC_Code_Old', index: 'UPC_Code_Old', width: 90, stype: 'text', hidden: true },
                    { name: 'Item_Desc', index: 'Item_Desc', width: 150 },
                     { name: 'Item_Desc_Old', index: 'Item_Desc_Old', width: 150, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'Size_UOM', index: 'Size_UOM', width: 60 },
                    { name: 'Size_UOM_Old', index: 'Size_UOM_Old', width: 60, hidden: true },
                    { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'Category', index: 'Category', width: 80 },
                    { name: 'Tax_Desc', index: 'Tax_Desc', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'WIC_CVV', index: 'WIC_CVV', width: 80 },
                    { name: 'Label', index: 'Label', width: 150 },
                    { name: 'Last_Movement', index: 'Last_Movement', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'Last_Purchase', index: 'Last_Purchase', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'Item_Added', index: 'Item_Added', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'Comment', index: 'Comment', width: 100, editable: true },
                    { name: 'Store_Number', index: 'Store_Number', width: 100, hidden: true }
                    ],
        multiselect: true,
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'UPC_Code',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        pager: '#pager2',
        width: 1100,
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        editurl: '',
        height: 60,
        onSelectRow: editRow,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
            var grid = $("#jqgItemDetails");
            if (name == 'Comment') {
                grid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'Comment', val);
            }
        },
        caption: '<span style="height:20px;color:#cc961a">UPC Item Details</span>'
    });

var lastSelection;

function editRow(id) {
    if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
        var grid = $("#jqgItemDetails");
        grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
        grid.jqGrid('editRow', id, { keys: true });
        lastSelection = id;
    }
}


function btnUPCShow_OnClientClick() {
    fillUPCDetailsGrid();
}
function fillUPCDetailsGrid() {
    var UPCCol = new Array();
    var UPCData = "", UPCLike = "", RangeFrom = "", RangeTo = "", FilterVal;
    FilterVal = document.getElementById('ddlFilter').value;
    if (FilterVal == 1) {
        UPCData = document.getElementById('txtUPC').value; // '77098103440,77098103450,77098103470,77098104423'; // document.getElementById('txtUPC').value;
        UPCCol = UPCData.split(',');
    }
    else if (FilterVal == 2) {
        UPCLike = document.getElementById('txtUPC').value;
    }
    else if (FilterVal == 3) {
        RangeFrom = document.getElementById('txtUPC').value;
        RangeTo = document.getElementById('txtRangeTo').value;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ItemInquiries.aspx/GetUPCDetails',
        data: JSON.stringify({ UPCCollection: UPCCol, UPCLike: UPCLike, UPCRangeFrom: RangeFrom, UPCRangeTo: RangeTo, Filter: FilterVal }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (Result) {
            var myjsongrid = $.parseJSON(Result.d);
            for (var i = 0; i < myjsongrid.Table.length; i++) {
                jQuery('#jqgItemDetails').jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, myjsongrid.Table[i]);
            }             
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me with this

Comment: @Oleg: Can you please help me with this